# error: illegal start of expression in some lambda expressions

Tags: java-8, playframework-2.4, typesafe-activator

I have the following function in java:

```
private static Predicate<SomeObject> isNotCancelled() {
    return i -> !i.getStatus().equals("Cancelled");
}
```

When using the following activator commands: compile, run, test or testOnly. Everything works well, no compilation error and the app works just as I expected.

But when I do activator testProd or activator stage the following error occurs:

```
[error] /path_to_class/SomeClass.java:34: error: illegal start of expression
[error]         return i -> !i.getStatus().equals("Cancelled")
[error]                   ^
```

Can someone help me understanding why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a Java 8 compiler?

Comment: Well I think and hope so. The only version that I have installed in my PC is javac 1.8.0_66.

Comment: How are you compiling your project? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: I'm using the command line "activator compile" command. My activator version is "activator-dist-1.3.6"

Comment: I have changed my activator start script to print the java version and it returned version 1.8.0_66

Comment: The Java version isn’t necessarily the *compiler* version. It also doesn’t say anything about the compliance level in the case of a compiler that supports multiple targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by upgrading activator, sbt and play versions to:

- activator-dist-1.3.7 (My previous version was 1.3.6)
- sbt 0.13.9 (My previous version was 0.13.8)
- play 2.4.4 (My previous version was 2.4.4)